# 4K monitor freezing computer possibilities?

Tags: graphics-card, freeze

Recently picked up a Dell XPS 8930 system.  Powerful enough one would think for a 4K monitor. i7/16 RAM/4 gig Nvidia Geforce 1050Ti video card, etc.  Was using an older Samsung 1080p monitor with it and all was fine.  Went out and got a Samsung 28" 4K monitor (U28E510D) and the problems began.

Seemed to work ok for a short while but then computer started having random freezes. Sometimes the mouse would completely freeze up, sometimes would just get a solid back or white screen. Only a complete power down would reboot it.  Tried every possible combination of resolution settings on it from default 4K to 2K and more - same issues.  Tried DVI, HDMI, and Display ports to connect it... same issues.  Plugged the old monitor back in and all is working fine again.

Any ideas on what would cause a monitor (I assume it was the monitor) to do these things?  Ran a Win diagnostics and at least that couldn't find any hardware issues with the video card. Drivers were up to date, etc. so I assume it's not a faulty video card (?).

Comment: What OS are you running? And what motherboard do you have?

Comment: Windows 10 Home.  System utility doesn't specify motherboard - just says "Dell - 8930 unnamed" or similar.

Comment: I suspect that the changed monitor is coincidental, these sound more like problems in software and hardware within the computer than things that a monitor is going to cause. If changing back to the old monitor doesn't help then try the Dell diagnostic and system test tools that should be installed. It sounds like a hardware fault of some description and might be worth seeing if there is anything in the [event logs](http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-use-event-viewer-in-windows-10/) around the time of the crashes.

Comment: I had bought these items at Costco and talked to their tech concierge and lucked out as I got someone who knew their stuff (or seemed to). Diagnostics came in ok. OLD monitor worked perfectly with no computer issues at all while using it. Picked up a HP QHD 2K monitor today and so far it's working ok. So I guess we'll see what happens in the next day or two.